# Notification sound not getting stopped iOS

Tags: ios, notifications

All
After removing notification using removeDeliveredNotifications, my app removes notification from tray but not able to stop sound.
Is there any way to stop sound of notification programmatically?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: When you want to sound the notifications, call: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
When you want to mute the notifications: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
to remove sound

Comment: Hello @DhavalRaval I know that ,but my issue is I need notification sound it playing 30 seconds custom sound I want to stop in-between once I clicked on notification